# List all blogs a user can admin

Tags: multisite, admin

Which is the best way to list all blogs a user can admin in a wordpress network?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
$user = get_current_user_id();
$blogs = get_blogs_user_can_admin($user);

function get_blogs_user_can_admin($user) {    
    $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user, true );
    foreach($blogs as $key => $blog) {
        switch_to_blog($blog->userblog_id);
        if( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) unset( $blogs[$key] );
        restore_current_blog();
    }
    return $blogs;
}
```